# "export" keyword in ndk-build Android.mk

Tags: android-ndk

When defining variable in the ndk build makefiles such as Android.mk, you can use or not, the keyword export.
What is the difference behavior between using it or assigning a variable value without it?

For example Android.mk make contains one of this two lines:

1. export MY_VAR:=5

or

2. MY_VAR:=5

Does the export suppose also to change the shell env variables? I don't see a difference when working with windows power-shell.

When using both I got the same behavior, both make the other make-files called recognize this variable.